# Regular Expression - select string between 2 expressions

Tags: regex

I would like to mark all strings between 2 strings with the regular expression.
Example:

https://regex101.com/r/Etfpol/1

I want regular expression to mark follow text:

- Solution changed from
- Resolved Time changed
- Updated By changed from

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D53aj.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookbehind and positive lookahead to check the tags.

```
(?<=<Name>Description<\/Name><Value>).*?(?=<\/Value>)
```

Match results

```
Solution changed from 
Resolved Time changed
Updated By changed from
```

If you prefer not to use them, this will work as well, but the full match will include the strings before and after your desired string.

```
(?:<Name>Description<\/Name><Value>)(.*?)(?:<\/Value>)
```